# How to Identify matching records in two tables?

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I have two tables with same column names. There are a total 40 columns in each table. Both the tables have same unique IDs. If I perform an inner join on the ID columns I get a match on 80% of the data. However, I would like to see if this match has exactly same data in each of the columns.

If there were a few rows like say 50-100 I could have performed a simple union operation ordered by ID and manually checked for the data. But both the tables contain more than 5000 records.

Is a join on each of the columns a valid solution for this or do I need to perform concatenation?

Comment: In postgresql it is possible to do that like 
`select * from tableA inner join tableb on(tablea.* = tableB.*) `

Comment: `select * from a union select * from b` then do group by `ID` column and check `having count(*) > 1`

Comment: Are all the rows unique? Particularly the column being joined on? If you have 6k records in A and 5k records in B, the following tells you how rows fully match, assuming neither table has duplicates.  `SELECT 11000-COUNT(*) present_both, COUNT(*)-5000 present_a_only, COUNT(*)-6000 present_b_only FROM (SELECT * FROM a UNION SELECT * FROM b) combined`

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have `N columns`, you can add `GROUP BY COL1,COL2,....COLN`

```
select * from table1
    union all
select * from table2
    group by COL1, COL2, ... , COLN
    having count(*)>1;
```

Reference: [link](https://ubiq.co/database-blog/compare-two-tables-mysql/#:%7E:text=MySQL%20Compare%20Two%20tables%20to%20Find%20Matched%20Records&text=First%20we%20do%20a%20UNION,tables%20to%20retain%20duplicate%20rows.&text=Next%2C%20we%20do%20a%20GROUP,the%20above%20query%20as%20subquery.)